# Comparing string in 2 files and appending the data in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I have 2 files 1.txt and 2.txt

1.txt contains below details

```
user = 10
user2 = 20
user3 = 30
```

2.txt contains below details

```
user = 25MB
user2 = 30MB
```

I need to compare both the files if the string matches in the files it should append the data from 1st file and if it does not match it should append 0 in shell script

Desired output

```
user = 10 25MB
user2 = 20 30MB
user3 = 30 0MB
```

I am using the command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2];next}!($1$2 in a)' 1.txt 2.txt
```

but not getting the desired output. I am new to shell scripting and looking for full implementation help.

Could you please help me with the syntax and implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $3; next } 
       { printf "%s = %s %s\n", $1, $3, ($1 in a ? a[$1] : "0MB") }' 2.txt 1.txt
user = 10 25MB
user2 = 20 30MB
user3 = 30 0MB
```

I chose to read the files in the opposite order, `2.txt`, then `1.txt`. The keys and values from `2.txt` are stored in the array `a`. For each line in `1.txt`, the value in the array corresponding to the key is used if present.